# What happened to the Too Localize Close option?

Tags: support

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127968/scoreboard-not-showing-up should be closed as too localized. However, I do not see that option for closing questions any more. What happened to that option?

Comment: Too localized has been murdered network wide:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too Localized [is gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye). All close reasons have been revamped, and we now have a set of custom close reasons that are more suited to our specific needs.